# Extract with regex when the same special character is used

Tags: regex

I've been trying to use Regex tools online, but none seem to be working. I am close but not sure what I'm missing.

Here is the Text:

> Valencia, Los Angeles, California - Map

I want to extract the first 2 letters of the state (so between "," and "-"), in this case "CA"

What I've done so far is:

```
[,/](.*)[-/]
$1
```

The output is:

> Los Angeles, California

If anything I thought I would at least just get the state.

Comment: what language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
,\s*(\w\w)[^,]*-
```

will capture `Ca` in group 1.

---

```
,       comma
\s*     whitespace
(\w\w)  capture the first two characters
[^,]*   make sure there's no comma up to the next dash
-
```

Answer (score 1):

```
,\s*(\S{2})[^,]*-
```

You're going to want to take just the first match.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use JavaScript.

Your regex fails this particular case because there are two commas in your input.

One possible fix is to modify the middle capture from `.` (any character) to `[^,]` (any character except comma). This will force the regex to match `California` only.

So, try `[,/]([^,]*)[-/]`. Here's a [demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/eV5fS5/1) of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
.*?,\s(\w\w)[^,]*-
```

`$1` is the first two letters you're looking for.